# subclassing with operator overloading c++

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, operator-overloading, raytracing

I am not the most experienced C++ programmer and new to this forum. 
I hope this first post follows the rules.

My goal is to write a simple raytracer, but I am stuck on how to extend one of my classes.
The problem lies with operator overloading, but also design-patterns (I think). Here is my code:

```
    class Vec{ //My vector class
        protected:
            double v[4]; //Fourth element not used...
        public:
            Vec();
            Vec (double i, double j, double k);

            Vec  operator+ (const Vec& vec) const;
            Vec  operator- (const Vec& vec) const;
            Vec & operator+=(const Vec& vec);
            Vec & operator-=(const Vec& vec);
            double operator*(const Vec& vec) const;
            Vec operator*(double scalar);
            //get operator
            double& operator[](unsigned int i);
            double operator[](unsigned int i) const;
            //Vector assignment operator
            Vec Vec::operator=(const Vec& vec);
            //Scalar assignment operator
            Vec Vec::operator=(double scalar);
    };

Vec Vec::operator+(const Vec& vec) const{
    return Vec(v[0]+vec.v[0], v[1]+vec.v[1], v[2]+vec.v[2]);
}
```

And

```
class Color : public Vec{
    protected:
        Vec col; //A Color should use all four elements in the array
                 //I.e Vec color(R,G,B,specular);
    public:
        //Vec Color::operator+(const Vec& vec) const; <-- this is wrong i know.
};
```

Just to be thorough, I do this in main:

```
Color myColor(1.2, 1.3, 2.3, 40);
Color myColor2(2.2, 3.4, 3.3, 30);
cout << (myColor+myColor2) << std::endl;
```

The program calls the Vec() default constructor returning an output of `(0,0,0)` which is clearly wrong....

Edit: The Vec class stores values like this

```
Vec::Vec () {
    v[0] = 0; v[1] = 0; v[2] = 0;
}
Vec::Vec (double i, double j, double k) {
    v[0] = i; v[1] = j; v[2] = k;
}
```

All overloaded operators work on `double v[4]` and return a Vec either a copy or reference.

**Question:** What is the most efficient/proper way to make Color utilize the operators from Vec? Would making the overloaded operators into template functions solve my problem (how?). Or should I take an entirerly different approach? I look forward to any help I can get, thank you.

Comment: Is Color supposed to have four compenents inherited from Vec and also have four more from a member variable col?

Comment: Apart from my first comment, it looks like you have a problem with needing covariant return types, but C++ isn't a language that does that.  You will have to consider templates.

Comment: @DarenW - for the first comment, No - but I think you just pointed out an error in my logic. I want Color to function similarly to a my vector Vec, all algebraic operations performed for the first three components of col... I know this is impossible since the operators in Vec are defined for three components, as such Im leaning towards template functionality, but very uncertain...

Comment: @DarenW - I have a basic understanding of how to use templates, I have in the past but this problem completely overwhelms me. I found very little syntax examples for this specific problem, ie - how to overload operators as templates + inheritance?

Comment: As DarenW pointed out, you are both deriving from vec and including an instance as a member. How do you store your values in the vec class? This may help us to help you implement that fourth parameter in your color class. I don't see templates being of any use here.

Comment: @Waldermort - Thank you for your comment, I appended some edits to clarify how I store the values.

Comment: @mike ok, I see. First, I would create a struct containing your 3 doubles, then define the vector as holding pointers to those `struct`. Use `new` to allocate and push it onto the vector. Also create protected a method in your base class that adds those structs. Now in your derived class, you can derive the struct to add a new double, again use `new` to create, and call the method in your base class to add it. This is know as `polymorphism`.

Comment: @Woldemort - Im having some syntax problems, could I maybe trouble you for a simple code example of this? Things Im mostly struggling with are e.g how to create a default constructor for Vec, filling each value in the struct... its simple stuff, but I've never done this before.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just something like this:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t N>
class Vector {
public:
  Vector();
  friend Vector operator+(const Vector& lh, const Vector& rh);
//...
private:
  double val[N];
};

typedef Vector<3> Vector3d;
typedef Vector<4> Color;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a couple of questions regarding this solution to fully understand it. Why is the operator+ now a friend function? Why two arguments instead of one? And also, Ive never used typedef - what does this do?

Comment: It is another way to implement operator+, in my example it is external function for Vector. typedef just introduce new name for type. After it you can write "Vectord3d var1, var2; Color var_for_color1;/*etc*/"

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you. Im testing this now.